How do I call child component method() via slots
I am migrating project from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and can't find a solution to a problem
Form.vue
<template>
    <form>
        <slot></slot>
    </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Setup, Vue } from 'vue-facing-decorator'
import { useSlots } from 'vue'

@Component({
    name: 'Form'
})
export default class Form extends Vue
{
    @Setup(() => useSlots())
    private slots!:any;

    public mounted():void
    {

    }

    public submit():void
    {
        for(let i in this.slots!.default!())
        {
            let child:any = this.slots!.default!()[i];

            if('FormSubmit' === child.type.name)
            {
                child.lock();
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>

FormSubmit.vue
<template>
    
</template>
<script lang="ts">

import { Component, Prop, Setup, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-facing-decorator'

@Component({
    name: 'FormSubmit',
    expose: ['lock']
})
export default class FormSubmit extends Vue
{
    public lock():void
    {
        console.log('lock the button');
    }
}
</script>


And the main view:
<template>
    <main>
        <Form>
            <FormSubmit />
        </Form>
    </main>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {Vue, Component } from 'vue-facing-decorator';

@Component
export default class FormView extends Vue
{
   
}
</script>

In Vue 2 I could loop through this.$children and access any child method but here it says that
child.lock is not a function
How can I then get the child from a slot and call that child's method?
Unfortunatelly ChatGPT is not helping this time, asking me to change submit() function into this
public submit():void
    {
        const defaultSlot = this.slots!.default?.();

        if (!defaultSlot) return;

        defaultSlot.forEach((vnode: any) => {
            if (vnode.type.name === 'FormSubmit') {
                const componentInstance = vnode.component;
                console.log(componentInstance);
                if (componentInstance && typeof componentInstance.exposed.lock === 'function') {
                    componentInstance.exposed.lock(); // Call the lock method
                }
            }
        });
    }

but componentIntance is always null
